# how to give a custom format to dateTimePicker in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, date-formatting

I want to show Date and Time in format like (2-13-2014). How would I do it.
Here is My code. I try this but it shows me Date and Time like this (2/13/2014). Please help me

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
     dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";

     MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to show `February 1, 2014` as `2-1-2014`, so this code should work

```
MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("M-d-yyyy"));
```

You can also change `"M-d-yyyy"` to any format you like, see @Dumisani's comment below for the reference.

Comment: You can also view other formats for future reference here: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The Format and CustomFormat of the DateTimePicker only relate to what's displayed in the DateTimePicker.  The Value property is a DateTime and has no specific connection to the control.  It's a binary value that has no format.  If you want to display a DateTime in a particular format then you have to specify that format when you convert it to a string, regardless of where it came from in the first place.  If you call ToShortDateString then you're going to use the default short date format for the system.